# How to upload a video in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, file, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a video and I get the path stored correctly in my database but I don't get the video in the folder that I want.

Here is my code:

```
$postvideo     = Postmedia::where('post_id',$id)->where('type','video')->first();

        if (isset($postvideo)) 
        {

            if ($request->video_link) {
                $postvideo->path = $request->video_link;
                $postvideo->typevid = $request->link;
            }
            else
            {
                File::delete($postvideo->path);
                if($request->hasFile('video_link_local'))
                    {

                        $file               = $request->file('video_link_local');
                        $filename           = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                        $path               = 'uploads/post/';
                        $file->move($path, $filename);
                        $postvideo->path    = $path.$filename;
                        $postvideo->ext     = ($request->video_link_local)->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $postvideo->typevid = $request->local;


                    }
            }
            $postvideo->save();
        }
```

the upload now works but in the case of accentuated filenames i get a problem in this line the name of the file is changed

```
$file->move($path, $filename);
```

like this for example : Présentation -> PrÃ©sentation !!!
So this creates a problem when i want to show the uploaded video

Comment: what is `the folder that i want' ? i assume /storage/app

Answer (score 1):

Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads , 
here docs explain how to handle all kind of file related stuff.

base example is

```
$file = $request->file('video_link_local');
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$path = '/uploads/post/';
$upload_path = Storage::putFileAs($path, $file, $filename);
$postmedia->path = $upload_path;
```

Then, when getting the file somewhere else where you have

```
// here you should already have fetched $postmedia

Storage::get($postmedia->path);
```

Comment: i'm using laravel 5.4 will this work ?

Comment: as you can see in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-uploads the methods are the same so yes